# Specific Texture Method using 'tilesets'?

Tags: texturing, workflow

Blender noob here...

I'm not sure which direction to go for texturing my low poly maps. I've tried texture painting directly onto and also assigning image materials to faces- but I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

I can see their material is pulled from a 2D tileset, have they somehow split it up into parts and are able to assign each part to specific faces?

Is there a method name anyone can tell me so I can google it?

EDIT: Noticed the UV map is used as the tileset, so maybe that's what I need to look more into...
[image]

Comment: The "UV map" you are looking at is a "Texture Atlas". They are make by assigning different materials to different areas of a mesh (UV defined), and then baking the result into one single image texture that represents all textures on the mesh.

Comment: Thanks! Will investigate